# Issue in displaying data that should just be visible for a particular ID not to all

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to display records of a particular job that has already been done by someone else before a new provider sees it. If the status is open, there should not be any information to be displayed as supposedly, no one has made any report about it. If the status is awarded, then necessary data should be displayed. Right now, the information to be shown are viewable. The problem the data is displayed in every job post even it is not the report for such a job.
Example,

```
Job ID | Title         | Description                            | Subject     | Job Status
2      | Math Tutor    | I need Math tutor! I need Math tuto... | Mathematics | Open
1      | English Tutor | Edited...                              | French      | Awarded
```

If I click "Open", I should not be able to see any record because it is still not done. If I click "Awarded", I should see details about the job. Right now, the data is showing properly for JOB ID 1 which was already awarded. However, the same data is shown as well in JOB ID 2.
How do I properly display the data in its proper place? I've been trying everything to do it. I included the JOB ID to be displayed to see if there's something wrong with it. But there's none, it shows JOB ID 1 in both jobs 1 and 2. How do I display it just in job 1 where it belongs?

Here's my code in controller:

```
public function view_tutors_tutorials()
{
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('tutorial_model');
    $this->load->model('auth_model');

    $data['subject_list'] = $this->array_to_select( $this->tutorial_model->get_all_subjects(), 'id','name');

    $my_preference = $this->tutorial_model->get_tutors_tutorials(isset($_GET['subject_id'])?$_GET['subject_id']:'0', isset($_GET['sort_by'])?$_GET['sort_by']:'');
    $data['my_preference'] = $my_preference;


    $this->load->view('provider/view_tutors_tutorials', $data);
}
```

and this in my model:

```
public function get_tutors_tutorials($subject_id = NULL, $sort_by = NULL) 
{
    //responsible for displaying job contracts for provider user.
     $this->db->select('tutorial.status as status, tutorial.client_id as client_id, tutorial.id as tutorial_id, subject.name as name, tutorial.title as title, tutorial.description as description, tutorial.start_date as start_date, tutorial.update_date_time as update_date_time,tutorial_proposal.provider_id as provider_id,provider.first_name as first_name,provider.last_name as last_name,tutorial.contract_status as contract_status,tutorial.provider_feedback as provider_feedback,tutorial.client_notetoself as client_notetoself,tutorial.client_feedback as client_feedback,tutorial.provider_notetoself as provider_notetoself,tutorial.material_used,tutorial.recommendation')->from('tutorial');
    $this->db->join('subject', 'subject.id = tutorial.subject_id');
    $this->db->join('tutorial_proposal', 'tutorial_proposal.provider_id = tutorial.provider_id');
    $this->db->join('provider', 'provider.id = tutorial_proposal.provider_id');
    $this->db->where('tutorial.status', 'Awarded');

    if ( ! empty($subject_id) ) 
    {
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
    }

    //if there's no sort selection made, the jobs will be sorted from newest to oldest
    if ( empty($sort_by)) 
    {
        $sort_by = "update_date_time desc";
    }

    $this->db->order_by($sort_by);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I look forward to getting any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove where condition for status in you model's query :
$this->db->where('tutorial.status', 'Awarded'); // this should be removed
Also make sure, your subject_id passed properly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've solved it before, but still thanks! :)